# B2B account creation

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, b2b

I have a normal B2C store. Now I would like to add B2B users to this shop.

How do I create a second user registration form for B2B users?

Users created here should automatically be added to a B2B user group but need a manual activation.

I found many extensions around this topic but the turn the shop into B2B online shops, like hiding prices. Maybe [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sitewards-b2bprofessional.html) will do the trick, not sure how to configure it for what I need...

**Update**

I created a CMS page for the b2b login and added the login form:

```
{{block type ="Mage_Customer_Block_Form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml" }}
```

With a copy of `login.phtml` I can create a custom login.

How do I change the customer group for user registration here? Also it would be nice to disable the account after creation.

**Update 2**

I removed the CMS page and created a new module with b2b page containing a block for login and a copy of the customer register block. I also copied and modified the `createpostAction()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a second form might not be the best solution. I'd like to suggest 2 other options.

1) creating a second website in Magento and putting a login in front of it using [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/login-only-catalog.html). Then when people register for this shop you can add then to a specific customer group automatically.

Some benefits are different prices, payment methods, shipping methods and display prices without tax on this shop while it doesn't affect the B2C shop.

2) A more simple approach is letting people sign up using the normal form and afterwards assigning them to a different customer group manually to give them access to customer group specific prices.

Comment: Could you add a customer entity type and tell it to display on registration forms? Based on that value during customer save you could shift to new groups?

Comment: Might also be a nice solution! Still you might want to verify that the customer really is B2B. Anyway, did some googling and found this extension that would do what you're proposing.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/15903/ EDIT: took a quick look at the code and looks pretty ok, does overwrite some customer section templates as expected